# compiling opencv in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, compilation

i have a file with only import:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "cxcore.hpp"
#include "highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

}
```

and i try to compile with g++ -I/usr/include/opencv -lopencv -lm m.cpp

but get whit error:

> In file included from /usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:46,
>                    from m.cpp:5:
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:214: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘void’
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:220: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘int’
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:226: error: ‘CV_INLINE’ does not name a type
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:516: error: ‘CV_DEPTH_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:522: error: ‘CV_DEPTH_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:522: error: ‘CV_CN_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
>   In file included from m.cpp:5:
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:70: error: template declaration of ‘cv::CV_EXPORTS cv::Size_’
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:71: error: template declaration of ‘cv::CV_EXPORTS cv::Point_’
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:72: error: template declaration of ‘cv::CV_EXPORTS cv::Rect_’
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:77: error: expected initializer before ‘fromUtf16’
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:78: error: expected initializer before ‘toUtf16’
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:80: error: expected initializer before ‘format’
>   /usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:82: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
>   m.cpp:38: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input

this is my copencv lib content:

```
alberto@zefiro:~$ ls /usr/include/opencv/
cvaux.h    cvcompat.h  cv.hpp        cvtypes.h  cvvidsurv.hpp  cxcore.h    cxerror.h  cxmat.hpp  cxoperations.hpp  highgui.h    ml.h
cvaux.hpp  cv.h        cvinternal.h  cvver.h    cvwimage.h     cxcore.hpp  cxflann.h  cxmisc.h   cxtypes.h         highgui.hpp
```

i'm on ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to properly include the headers `-I` (capital i) and libraries `-l` (lowercase L).

On the newest OpenCV versions you should do:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

And then try to compile it with:

```
g++ m.cpp -o app `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Note: if you execute only `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` in the command line you will see the paths and libraries you need to include in the g++ command line.

Comment: sigh. this do compile but remaind me at this problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/9088228/433685

Comment: I always forget the name of the pkg-config utility. Thanks for the simple solution!

Comment: Suppose I have an openCV version installed and built in a directory (the global version is different). How should I change the command you posted to compile and build   my project with the new local version of openCV?

Comment: Execute `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` to see the exact parameters the global version passes to **g++**. Then, just copy the same flags and use your local paths instead. Simple!

Comment: I installed 4.2 from source and had to do the following steps while building: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13154#issuecomment-456652297

Comment: For opencv4, the command is `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`

Answer (score 13):

if your development environment does not have `pkg-config` and because of this the [accepted answer by karlphilip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097071/1979048) is not practical, or, you need to know the minimal set of libraries required to link your application, then assuming code such as

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

you can add library arguments from the following list sequentially from the top until you find the minimal set of arguments that you need:

```
  -lopencv_core
  -lopencv_imgproc
  -lopencv_highgui
  -lopencv_ml
  -lopencv_video
  -lopencv_features2d
  -lopencv_calib3d
  -lopencv_objdetect
  -lopencv_contrib
  -lopencv_legacy
  -lopencv_flann
```

For example, the C source code listed at the top of this post compiles and links cleanly with only

```
gcc hello.c -o hello \
    -I /usr/include/opencv \
    -L /usr/lib \
    -lopencv_core \
    -lopencv_imgproc
```

on my old x86_64 Ubuntu 12.04 box.

Assuming C++ code such as

```
#include "core/core.hpp"
#include "highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    return 0;
}
```

then you would compile and link with

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello \
    -I /usr/include/opencv2 \
    -L /usr/lib \
    -lopencv_core \
    -lopencv_imgproc
```

Comment: I tried compiling the g++ version from this guy's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8 on the command line because I wanted to try it without VS. It compiles, but when I run the program nothing happens.

Comment: Nevermind, It's a missing windows dll file problem. Thank you for your above answer though.

Comment: I need to add opencv_contrib but it is not in the package list as i can see it using the command  pkg-config --libs opencv.

Comment: What is reason behind that you need to put both -I (searching include file) and -L (searching file during link time)? Also would you share, why you need to put "-lopencv_core" and "-lopencv_imgproc" additionally.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use CMake to compile `OpenCV` with `G++`, this way is more suitable, I think.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(YOUR_PROJECT_NAME)

set(CMAKE_GXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion  -pedantic -std=gnu11")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(YOUR_EXCUTABLE YOUR_CODE_SOURCE_FILES)
target_link_libraries(YOUR_EXCUTABLE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: With this cmake file I had to change the includes to "  #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

Comment: @jjcf89 great, happy to help. The use of CMake is very suitable for compiling, you should really consider using it. For me, it helped me a lot, and it's time saving too.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the accepted answer is a bit old.

At least for OpenCV 4.X, the most recently release today, you can use:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

and compile your program by something like:

```
g++ your_program_file.cpp -o your_program `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Note `opencv4` and not only `opencv`.

For example, using the command above to compile the following  `your_program_file.cpp` file:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {

    std::cout << "The current OpenCV version is " << CV_VERSION << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

And running:

```
./your_program
```

Outputs:

```
The current OpenCV version is 4.4.0
```

Which indeed matches with my current OpenCV settings.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download source files in [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/releases.html) folder and
   [install-opencv.sh](https://opencv.org/releases.html) script.
2. By running script file you
   automatically install needed files for opencv. Run the following
   code:

   ```
   chmod +x install-opencv.sh
   ./install-opencv.sh
   ```

In case if you install different version of the library please update the first line of version inside the installation script.
For more information use [this](http://www.daslhub.org/unlv/wiki/doku.php?id=opencv_install_ubuntu) tutorial. Compile it with the next line:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` example.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```