# Compiling opencv program cause gcc -I/usr/local/lib test.cpp test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, undefined-reference

There is a error when compiling opencv program program simple includes  `#include <opencv2/core.hpp>`

I compiled it with this command

```
 g++ test.cpp -o app `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

[compiling opencv in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094941/compiling-opencv-in-c)

This is full error

```
gcc -I/usr/local/lib test.cpp 
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
```

I compiled and install the opencv by looking at this page https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#building-opencv-from-source-using-cmake-using-the-command-line

The code is from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html

Also my opencv so files are located at /usr/local/lib

Error also says

```
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

but I searched /usr directory there is no opencv.pc file

### Update

Compiling program after updating my compile command This error throws

```
 $g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ test.cpp 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccuJvWgF.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::empty() const'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `cv::applyColorMap(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x355): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

### Update 2

when now compiling

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ test.cpp
```

it throws this error. There are many opencv so files in /usr/local/lib do I need to include specific opencv so files to compile the code in the link

```
 in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::empty() const'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `cv::applyColorMap(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x355): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit sta
```

Comment: Unless `opencv2/` is in your `usr/local/lib/` directory, you need to have an `-I` include path pointing to it.  Could this be your issue?

Comment: @meaning-matters I tried same error caused `g++ -I/usr/local/lib test.cpp 
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: You say you compile with "g++ test.cpp -o app `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`" but then show the error output from "g++ -I/usr/local/lib test.cpp": can you clarify the precise commands you use to compile and link?  Also, please edit your question to show the output from `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`.

Comment: @user786 Is your `opencv2/` directory in `/usr/local/lib/`?

Comment: @G.M. both these command complain about same header files. So same error. Did this clarify

Comment: @meaning-matters yes that's where all so files for opencv living

Comment: @user786 What does `ls /usr/local/lib/opencv2/core.hpp` say?

Comment: @user786 It not the .so files that matter, it is the .hpp files. Normally they would be in `/usr/local/include` not `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: i@meaning-matters path for headers are  -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2

Comment: @john I have updated my question with updated compile  command please check now functions and class are undefined

Comment: @user786 What you are missing now is the opencv libraries to link with (the .so files).. You need something like `-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv` but I'm not exactly sure, and it depends on exactly where you installed opencv.

Comment: It would have been better if you had installed opencv with a *package manager* instead of trying to do it yourself. That way your original command would have worked.

Comment: @user786 If that's where the OpenCV headers are, why didn't you have/show `-I/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2` in your commands?  (I've downvoted because your question and comments lack clarity.)

Comment: @meaning-matters ok now I have include -I and -L both please check my updated question. Thanks for help

Comment: @john my opencv so files all of them are in /usr/local/lib directory and I included both -L/usr/local/lib and -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ with `g++ -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/  test.cpp` but now all opencv classes and functions calls are throwing exception undefined

Comment: maybe I have to include specific so file in -L all of them  but not sure which so files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `-L` option you should specify the library search path.

Then with `-l` options you specify the library names you'd like to link against.

So in your case I'd expect to see `-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core`.  Note that the `-l` name has the `lib` prefix  and file extension omitted.  (You may need more OpenCV libraries.)

Seeing your struggles, I think it would be good to read a general tutorial about compiling and linking C/C++ programs (on your platform).

Comment: Yes I think u meant -lopencv_core to specify specific library. Also with -L/usr/local/lib can u please confirm

Comment: @user786 It's unclear to me what's unclear you and what you want me to confirm.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I moved some code from OpenCV2 to OpenCV4, it appears you are using some OpenCV4 as well. My fix was to not include opencv2/ but to include opencv4/opencv2/. Not exactly sure what about that made it work, I did that way too long ago, but it worked since.